# 2D visualisation Benchmarking for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, performance

I've just started working as a GIS technician in a land agency firm. I'm handling large datasets such as historic house sales (~500,000 rows of data per year) and executing heavy duty operations, sub-sequentially putting pressure on a laptop and PC which I've been given to work on. Currently I'm concentrating on 2D visualisation of data but anticipate 3D will come into play further down the line. I'm using QGIS running at version 2.18.5.

**Laptop:**

```
Windows 10, 64 bit
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz 2601Mhz, 2 cores, 4 logical processors
Installed Physical Memory 8.00 GB   
Total Available Physical Memory 7.89 GB
Available Physical Memory 3.74 GB
Total Virtual Memory 17.8 GB
Available Virtual Memory 12.7 GB GB
AMD Radeon R7 M370 Graphics Card
```

**PC:**

```
Windows 7, 64 bit
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1225 v5 @ 3.30GHz, 3301 Mhz, 4 cores, 4 logical processors
Installed Physical Memory 8.00 GB
Total Available Physical Memory 7.89 GB
Available Physical Memory 3.85 GB
Total Virtual Memory 15.8 GB
Available Virtual Memory 11.7 GB
(On-board) Intel HD Graphics P530 Graphics Card
```

I've created a stress test with the following shapefile, (EPSG '27700') operating an 'inverse' distance buffer on it (conduct at your own choosing): https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e4wyp13mwbb85d/Benchmark%20Test.zip?dl=0
The shapefile shows all the planning local authorities in the UK, the boundaries of which are made up with many vertices. The test with 'shrink' the polygon features due to a negative buffer setting. The algorithm is the most demanding I've come across hence I've set it up to be my benchmark test.

Both PC and Laptop choke at 95% if distance is set at '-1000' and segments left at '5'. At 2 hours into the algorithium, there was no progress beyond 95% although it took <5 mins to get to 95%.

If the buffer is increased to '-100' the laptop and PC both manage it in good time (min:sec).

**Laptop:** *Time: 5:50*

**PC:**  *Time: 4:30*

The company is planning to get some more powerful hardware for me. The test is purely meant as a comparison and to gain some perspective.

If you are running shorter times, or have a good perception for what PC component might make QGIS run faster what is it?

Comment: For hardware recommendations there is the [hardwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ poly geo OK, I'll transfer the question over. However it seems only 5% of the questions there seem to be answered. If it's alright, I'll leave the question up here too. Do you need me to expand on this any more for you to make the question live again?

Comment: Available physical RAM (DDR3+) is probably more important than CPU speed for most geoprocessing tasks using QGIS. All GIS PC in our work environment must have 32GB RAM or more for 64 bit OS. We deal with millions or rows changing daily.

Comment: Hardware Recommendations has answers for 67% of its questions: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations.  Normally, cross-posting is frowned upon but to give Beta sites help towards their 10 questions per day target I want to encourage questions to be posted there.

Comment: For this question to get my vote for re-opening it would need to remove the open-endedness of "can you make any suggestions and/or comparisons?"  Rather than asking for a hardware recommendation or requesting that people run your test and report their results (which means that you are asking for a list of results) simply focus it on "The operation I'm executing with this shapefile is an 'inverse' fixed distance buffer."  You could describe the precise test that you are performing.

Comment: Then describe your results and the precise hardware that you are receiving them on, and then ask a focussed question like "Would more RAM improve the performance?".  From that answerers could include in their answers a description of their own hardware and the result they get on the same or a similar test.  Your content is not far from doing that already so it is really the closing question that de-focuses it.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've edited the question to try and pin-point the query. I think you have an idea for what I'm asking, so if you feel it needs further tweaking I do not mind if you slice it up. Perhaps deleting these comments before publishing the question would make it tidier. Leaving Mapperz's comment may be beneficial though. I've updated the question on hardware recommendations (no comments there yet)